# Oracle 10g unpivot returning values in one column and creating month column

Tags: sql, oracle

We just found out that the new database we have been given access to is Oracle 10g, so we are unable to use fcn like UNPIVOT.

We have a table like this..

```
SUBMISSION  COUNTRY CPM_ID  PFM_ID  T_AREA  CNTRY_CODE  V_TYPE  RES_CAT  JAN_2014  FEB_2014
01-JUN-2014  USA     10      24      TEST1   USA         V1      210      5          10
01-AUG-2014   UK      20     30      TEST2   UK          V1      213     20          30
```

The desired output would look like this...

```
SUBMISSION  COUNTRY  CPM_ID  PFM_ID  T_AREA  CNTRY_CODE  V_TYPE  RES_CAT  MONTH       VALUE
 01-JUN-2014  USA     10      24      TEST1   USA         V1      210     01-JAN-2014 5   
 01-JUN-2014  USA     10      24      TEST1   USA         V1      210     01-FEB-2014 10    
 01-AUG-2014   UK      20     30      TEST2   UK          V1      213     01-JAN-2014  20
 01-AUG-2014   UK      20     30      TEST2   UK          V1      213     01-FEB-2014  30
```

I am working with a query like this...but I cannot get the month column to come out right...

```
select *
from (select t.submission,
t.country,
t.cpm_id,
t.pfm_id,
t.t_area,
t.cntry_code,
t.v_type,
t.res_cat,
  (case 
    when n.n = 1 then JAN-2014 
    when n.n = 1 then FEB-2014 end) as value
    from table1 t cross join
       (select FEB_2014 as n from dual union all
        select FEB_2014 from dual) n
     ) s
where value is not null;
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
select t.submission,
      t.country,
      t.cpm_id,
      t.pfm_id,
      t.t_area,
      t.cntry_code,
      t.v_type,
      t.res_cat,
      n.d,
      case when n.d = '01-JAN-2014' then t.jan_2014 else t.feb_2014 end value
from table1 t
cross join
(
  select '01-JAN-2014' d from dual
  union all
  select '01-FEB-2014' d from dual
) n;
```

Comment: This query returns ORA-00904: "VALUE": invalid identifier

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I thought `value` was coming from your table, I just realized you computed it. I just removed the `where` clause.